# Adding an image to the home page

Tags: media, navigation, theming

I'm using the Zen sub-theme. I don't want all the new stuff on the site showing on the home page so I'm editing page--front.tpl.php. Removed print render($page['content']). But now I want to add some static text and and image to my home page.

How do I go about doing this basic thing?

Comment: I think the real issue here is you're seeing new pages automatically posted to the front page, correct? There's a simple solution to stop this behavior: go to admin/config/system/site-information (Drupal 7) and set a default front page (node/X).  Other options are the front page module, panels, blocks, etc. In other words, there's really no reason to alter page--front.tpl.php as that's the last place the next developer will check.

Comment: @Webdrips you got it right, thank you! Your points are noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a node, and put this node (eg. node/15) in the admin/config/system/site-information default frontpage field.

Otherwise you can also create a custom  page with hook_menu() like this:

```
$items[path] = array(
    'title callback' => 'page title',
    'page callback' => 'page_callback',
    'access callback' => 'access_callback',
    'type' => MENU_SUGGESTED_ITEM,
);
```

and in page_callback() you can return your  custom theme template/function.

Or simply use some contributed modules like "Empty Page", "Front Page", "Empty Front Page" and others..

Comment: thanks! one question of clarification: does hook_menu() always have to be in custom module or is it ok to call it from template.php?